# apply sequence values to ordered subset of table records

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "dummy" with the following columns:

```
| id | name | position | updated_at | status |
```

I want to update the column "position" with values from a sequence, only for the records with status=active and ordered desc by "updated_at".Is this possible ?

A close query, but not valid because of the 'order by' clause, is:

```
Update dummy d1 set position = nextval('positions_sequence') 
    from dummy d2 where d1.id = d2.id and d2.status = 'active' 
    order by d2.updated_at desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily archieve this with stored proc using loop:

```
FOR d1 IN SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE status = active order by updated_at desc LOOP
new_position := nextval('positions_sequence');
EXECUTE Update dummy set position = new_position where id = d1.id;
END LOOP;
```